# change my url from depending on id to title | django

Tags: django

I've a url for checking books by its id:

```
path('book/<int:book_id>', views.book, name='book'),
```

view:

```
def book(request, book_id):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=book_id)

    context = {
        'book': book
    }

    return render(request, 'media/book.html', context)
```

but my client asked me to change it for the title instead but I tried it and it didn't seem to work, there are no examples for it in the docs either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the url to  `'book/<str:book_title>'`, and also adjust your function accordingly:

```
def book(request, book_title):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, yourfieldfortitle=book_title)
    ...
```

It might be helpful to try accessing the url first with a pattern that you know must work. NOTE: this makes the strong assumption that a book is identified by its title, otherwise using the primary key is the proper way even if it doesn't "look nice" as a url.

Comment: the browser uses the '%20' instead of spaces as you know is there's a way around this? like changing it to '-' and that changing it back in the view? I know how to do it in js but idk if its possible in Python.

Comment: Well, in your View controller you could do something like book_title.replace('-',' ' ') to go back to spaces. As for how you get to the url, whatever templates in your are redirecting to book/yourtitlehere should use get_absolute url and inside your model for a book you just define the get_absolute_url to do the opposite operation i.e. return "/"+title.replace(" ","-").

Answer (score 1):

The NOTE in the answer above does not take SEO into account.  For SEO purposes, it is much better to have a url that includes the name of the book rather than just the ID.  If you are already in production, then remember to do a permanent redirect in your view from all ID-based urls to the slug-based url.  Your Book model definition (or Product or whatever you've called it) should include a slugified field:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', unique=True, blank=True)
    other_fields...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Create slug for SEO
        #Don't ever change once established since is part of the URI
        if self.slug is None or self.slug == '': 
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```